# How to merge Laravel's Baum hierarchy trees into a single tree?

Tags: php, recursion, laravel-5, tree

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and [etrepat/baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) package for implementing nested sets on my Category model.

I've a collection of categories, for each one I get their ancestor's [hierarchy tree](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#hierarchy-tree) like this:

```
$category->getAncestorsAndSelf()->toHierarchy();
```

For example, let's say I have 4 categories: `Category C`, `Category D`, `Category E` and `Category F`. And each tree looks like this:

- Category A

  - Category B

    - **Category C**
- Category A

  - Category B

    - **Category D**
- Category A

  - Category B

    - Category C

      - **Category E**
- Category A

  - **Category F**

I'm trying to merge them into one tree like this:

- Category A

  - Category B

    - **Category C**

      - **Category E**
    - **Category D**
  - **Category F**

So far I've tried the [merge()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-merge) function and a custom recursive function with no luck, I always end up with duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- get all Categories involved in the hierarchy
- get rid of duplicates
- create Hierarchy using `Baum\Extensions\Eloquent\Collection`

```php
use Baum\Extensions\Eloquent\Collection as BaumCollection;

// ... 

$categoriesAndAncestors = $category
    ->flatMap(function ($cat) {
        return $cat->getAncestorsAndSelf();
    })
    ->uniqueStrict(function ($cat) {
        return $cat->id;
    });

$result = BaumCollection::make($categoriesAndAncestors)->toHierarchy();
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I won't be able to test it since I don't work with Laravel anymore.

Comment: I've found it after 3 years from posting, so maybe after another 3 years, it'll help someone :D